# Use a variable to represent another variable?

Tags: function-construction, variable

I'm trying to create a list of functions by replacing variables in a template. I tried this:

```
In[1]:= Table[Function[{x,y}, (x + y) v], {v, {x,y}}]
Out[1]= {Function[{x, y}, (x + y) v], Function[{x, y}, (x + y) v]}
```

But these functions have `v` in them. I was expecting to get:

```
{Function[{x, y}, (x + y) x], Function[{x, y}, (x + y) y]}
```

I thought this would work because I can do something similar with `Solve`:

```
In[2]:= Table[Solve[(x + y) v == 1 && x == y], {v, {x, y}}]
Out[2]= {{{x -> -(1/Sqrt[2]), y -> -(1/Sqrt[2])}, …
```

This is equivalent to:

```
In[3]:= {Solve[(x + y) x == 1 && x == y], Solve[(x + y) y == 1 && x == y]}
Out[3]= {{{x -> -(1/Sqrt[2]), y -> -(1/Sqrt[2])}, …
```

It seems like it's replacing `v` with `x`/`y` in the `Solve` example, but not the `Function` example. Substituting `Function[{x,y}, (x + y) Evaluate[v]]` for `Function[{x,y}, (x + y) v]` doesn't help. What's going on here? How can I generate a list of similar functions?

Comment: `Function[{x, y}, (x + y) #] & /@ {x, y}`

Comment: This is an effect of `Function`'s `HoldAll` attribute. Use `/.` or something like what Bob Hanlon is suggesting to work around it.

Comment: @eyorble If that's the case, then why doesn't Evaluate[v] help? It seems like it should, according to https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EvaluationOfExpressions.html#24449007

Comment: @ppm: `Evaluate` evaluates before `Table`, so `Table`'s internal expression is still a function with `HoldAll`.

Answer (score 1):

The question is similar to how to construct a series of pure functions.

```
Function /@ Table[(Slot[1] + Slot[2]) v, {v, {Slot[1], Slot[2]}}]
```

Some codes similar with @BobHanlon in the comment is

```
Outer[Function[{x, y}, (x + y) #] &, {x, y}]
```

Comment: Is there any reason to use Outer instead of Map?